# execute if statement if a value found in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I have a piece of code which sole purpose is to find a desired value in a multidimensional array and if a match is found execute a if statement.

i have used `array_search()` method which returns the index of the match.So it means if match is found in the first index it returns that index which is 0.That is false by definition.

So when match is found in the first index ,my if statement doesn't get executed.How to solve this porblem?

```
$arr = array(

   0 =>array(
       'name' => 'mr.x',
       'id' => 1
   ),
   1 =>array(
       'name'=>'mr.y',
       'id'  =>2
   )

);

$match = array_search(2,array_column($arr,'id'));

echo $match;

if($match){

    echo 'a match found !';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a match is not found, it will return false. You want a strict equality check:

```
if ($match !== false) {
    echo 'a match found !';
}
```

You are correct--since `0` is falsy, you'll never get into the if block if the value is the first in the array. So you must check if the return value is specifically false, not just falsy.

You can see examples of this in the [PHP documentation regarding array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: will it execute if $match = 0 ? (-_-)

Comment: Yep! It will only not execute if `$match` is actually `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!==` or `===`.

```
if(($key = array_search( ... )) !== false){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to use this recursive search to get the value and execute the code.

```
$found = recursive_array_search($search_item, $your_array);
if ( $found ){
    echo 'a match found !';
}

function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```